# FindFirstDevice() fails to find the driver setup on the fly

Tags: c++, c, windows-mobile, windows-ce

Here is what I am doing:
1. Boot the windows mobile device
2. Create a registry key `HKLM\Drivers\BuiltIn\<mydriver>` for my test **driver** using `RegCreateKeyEx` and setup the registry key using `RegSetValueEx` (with IClass, Flags, Dll and Order values) so my driver loads on subsequent warm boots
3. Reboot the device (my test driver loads and does what it is supposed to do as expected)
4. Use `FindFirstDevice(DeviceSearchByGuid, ...)` to get a handle to my driver (**Problem#1: This fails with error code 0x12 meaning it failed to find my device with the specified GUID**). I am assuming that my driver will be advertised when it is loaded after reboot since I have defined the IClass value in its registry.
5. Use the handle to unload my driver
6. Delete the registry key that I created above in #2 (**Problem#2: This fails with error code 0x5 - error_access_denied**)

Note: Steps 2, 4, 5, 6 are done using my test **application**

Observation:
1. I am able to delete the key after creating it as long as device is not rebooted. However, I get the 'permission denied' error when I create the key and try to delete it after rebooting the device.
2. I tried removing the code that loads the driver after reboot (by setting the Flag to DEVFLAGS_NOLOAD) to see if that has something to do with the permission issue while trying to delete the registry. I still could not delete the registry.

Comment: If you are running on a system with UAC enabled, does your *application* have administrator privileges (not your user account, but process)?

Comment: Thanks for the response @freedompeace. I confirmed (with security experts' help) that my app has needed permissions to delete the registry key. I couldn't figure out what is causing the access issues yet. For now, I am moving forward by changing the key values (in step 6) so that it won't load after reboot. I am assuming that leaving the key in the registry won't harm.

Comment: Are you sure that the driver loads prior to the application which is trying to get its handle?